# Wrong alignment of TextInputLayout and Spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-textinputlayout, android-5.1.1-lollipop, samsung-galaxy

I wanna put `TextInputLayout` and `Spinner` in one line. Also, I need show errors on `TextInputLayout`. It works fine on devices with `Android 6.1+ (I tested it on Sony with 6.1+ and on the emulator with 8.0).But on my Samsung with Android 5.1 this looks like this:

**Layout in editor**

[image: Layout in editor]

**Layout on devices with Android 6.1+**

[image: Layout on devices with Android 6.1+]

**Wrong layout on Samsung**

[image: Wrong layout on Samsung]

I also set diffirent backgrounds to elements in Layout (LinearLayout, TextInputLayout, EditText, Spinner). And sizes and positioning of elements seems correct. Looks like promblem is that Spinner on Samsung just draws line is lower than expected

**Colored layout experiment**

[image: Colored layout experiment]

**My xml code:**

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="18dp"
        tools:context="com.app.MyActivity" >

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="-10dp">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_new_amount"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:errorEnabled="true"
                app:hintEnabled="false">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edit_new_amount"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="46dp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/hint_amount"
                    android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
                    android:singleLine="true" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_currency"
                style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
                android:layout_width="98dp"
                android:layout_height="46dp"
                android:spinnerMode="dialog"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

How to fix it? This is bug of Android 5.1 or samsung firmware?

Answer (score 0):

1) now apply gravity into liner layout "start|centre"

Answer (score 0):

one library provide feature to maintain layout size in all device.you can use that.
add below dependency in app level gradle file ..

```
 implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.4'
```

then after define size in this format like ..

```
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_50sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
    android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
```